# Python REST POST with basic auth

Tags: python, rest, basic-authentication

I am trying to get a POST request working with Python 3 which will submit a json payload to a platform which uses basic auth. I am getting a 405 status error and believe it may be resulting from the formatting of my payload. I'm learning Python as I go and still unsure about when to use ' vs ", objects vs arrays and the syntax of some requests. Searching, I haven't been able to find similar issues posting an array with basic auth. Here's what I've got at the moment:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://sampleurl.com'
payload = [{'value': '100','utcRectime': '09/23/2018 11:59:00 PM','comment': "test",'correctionValue': '0.0','unit': 'C'}]
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url, auth=('username','password'), data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)


print (r)
```

Testing in the API swagger, the CURL contains the following formatting:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '[{"value": "100","utcRectime": "9/23/2018 11:59:00 PM","comment": "test","correctionValue": "0.0","unit": "C"}]'
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you want to `dump` the list to a string. `requests` will beat the python data structure into the right payload. The `requests` library is also smart enough to generate the proper headers if you specify the `json` keyword argument.

You can try:

```
r = requests.post(url, auth=('username','password'), json=payload)
```

Furthermore, sometimes sites block unknown user agents. You can try to pretend you're a browser by doing:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.post(url, auth=('username','password'), json=payload, headers=headers)
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried removing the dump and then running it both with and without the header that you suggested but unfortunately still returning a 405 status.

Answer (score 1):

From requests 2.4.2 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests), the "json" parameter is supported. No need to specify "Content-Type". So the shorter version:

```py
requests.post('https://sampleurl.com', auth=(username, password), json={'value': '100','utcRectime': '09/23/2018 11:59:00 PM','comment': "test",'correctionValue': '0.0','unit': 'C'})
```

Details:

```py
import requests
import json

username = "enter_username"
password = "enter_password"

url = "https://sampleurl.com"
data = open('test.json', 'rb')

r = requests.post(url, auth=(username, password), data=data)

print(r.status_code) 
print(r.text)
```